# Difference between creating or reusing the object reference in java

Tags: java

I am sorry but I could not think any better title for the question. Could you please help me understand the difference between these two scenario.

```
public class Temp {
int value;

public Temp(int i) {
    this.value = i;
}

public void method(Vector<Temp> vec) {
    Temp temp=null;

    // first case, creating new object but reusing the reference
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        temp = new Temp(i);
        vec.add(temp);
    }

    // second case, object and reference are new
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Temp temp1 = new Temp(i);
        vec.add(temp1);
    }

}
}
```

Which implementation should be best practice to follow.

Comment: You also have the possibility of creating and adding directly: `vec.add(new Temp(i));` which is what I would prefer. But if would depend on your company policy or, if it's just for you, your preference.

Comment: Reusing objects can make sense, but I have never seen a time where reusing the variable is more efficient (perhaps it it microscopically but not noticably)

Comment: @AntonH, I can not use that because there are so many parameter I am setting using setter method after creating object.

Comment: Does the three possibilities leads to the same thing due to compiler optimization ?

Comment: @JulienBreuil I see only two possibilities, and they lead to almost the same bytecode.

Comment: @Ashish If you can only use those 2 methods, I would personally go with the second. But again, personal preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to maintain the variables in their narrowest scope. In this case, second case seems better than case 1. The only benefit for case 1 would be if you really need to know which was the last element added to your `Vector` (which in this case seems to be really odd).

Comment: Thank you for you valuable opinion.

Comment: @LuiggieMendoza Would there be any differences in terms of performance between case 1 and case 2?

Comment: @jbaille1991 no, there's no performance improvement on any of these cases.

Comment: Realize this is an old thread, but didn't want to start a duplicate. Can someone (@LuiggiMendoza ?) provide facts to back up the answer? I'm wondering the same thing as the OP.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness what are you looking for? An example of why using the latter is better than the former?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer second option than first one to **make sure that it's always initialized at the time of declaration**.

You can't declare `temp` as `final` in first option.

Note : Do not leave local variable uninitialized. It should be `Temp temp = null;` in first option.

Comment: Temp temp; makes sense if the next statements will assign a value to temp. It is wrong(and compiler will complain) if there is only a branch in the next statements that will assign a value and if this is expected, yes, then temp must be null

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Sorry I didn't gt it. What you want to say?

Comment: I disagree with your note :)